# The space of bounded linear operators into a banach space is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

This is a common theorem and is proven in many books. I am confused with a particular part of the proof. This image has been taken from [Christopher Heils notes](http://calvino.polito.it/~terzafac/Corsi/functional_analysis/pdf/chap3.pdf).

[image]

If $A_n$ is a cauchy sequence in $B(X,Y)$ then we know that $||An-Am||\rightarrow 0$ as $n,m\rightarrow 0$. It then follows that for any $f\in X$ it must be that $||A_nf-A_mf||\rightarrow 0$. But I do not understand how we get $||A_nf-A_mf||\leq||A_n-A_m|| \,||f||$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the (usual) norm on $B(X, Y)$:
$$\|A\| := \sup_{\|x\|_X \le 1} \|Ax\|_Y.$$
Then, for all $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$, we have
$$\|A\| \ge \left\|A\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|_X}\right)\right\|_Y = \frac{\|Ax\|_Y}{\|x\|_X} \implies \|A\|\|x\|_X \ge \|Ax\|_Y.$$
(The final inequality also holds trivially for $x = 0$ too.)

So, just apply this principle here! We have,
$$\|A_n f - A_m f\| = \|(A_n - A_m)f\| \le \|A_n - A_m\| \|f\|.$$

Comment: I realized my mistake soon after asking the question. Your answer was posted while I was typing my answer. I will accept your answer when the time limit allows it.

Comment: In the first part, you have some $\leq $ instead of $\geq $ by definition of the sup.

Comment: That definition Theo provided is correct. 
Could you also confirm that this is correct: $\| A_nf-A_mf\|$ is a cauchy sequence because $\|f\|$ is a finite constant and $\|A_n-A_m\|$ is a cauchy sequence.

Comment: @Paul Whoops!$\hspace{0pt}$

Comment: @T.Stark Sort of, not exactly. It's more because $T \mapsto Tf$ is a Lipschitz map, with Lipschitz map, in that $\|Tf - Sf\| \le K\|T - S\|$, where $K = \|f\|$. As such, it is uniformly continuous, hence Cauchy continuous, and $A_n$ is a Cauchy sequence that maps to Cauchy sequence $A_n f$. Note that $\|A_n - A_m\|$ is not even really a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I did not properly think about the definition of the operator norm.

Being explicit: We let $\|\cdot\|_Y$ be the norm on $X$, $\|\cdot\|_Y$ be the norm on $Y$, $\|\cdot\|_B$ be the operator norm. Recall that $\|A\|_B=\sup_{x\in X\{0\}}\frac{\|Ax\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}$.

This gives the result $\|A_nx-A_mx\|_Y\leq \|A_n-A_m\|_B \|x\|_X$.